# Edits not being approved/rejected for quite some time

Tags: support, editing

I haven't been able to edit questions for a few weeks because "*[I] have too many pending edits. Further edits cannot be submitted until prior edits have been approved*".

Has nobody been accepting/rejecting edits lately or am I otherwise stuck? Can this be remedied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bit of a backlog, yes. I guess the community members haven't been doing their duty (or not enough of them anyway as it takes a few votes normally for each edit).

I've cleared the queue.